# Flutter WebView giving error Name not resolved for local web app hosted on IIS

Tags: android, flutter, iis, webview

I have hosted a test web app on my local IIS(by adding domain name in `hosts` file) and it is working fine in browser.
But when I am trying to access it through [WebView](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) flutter then getting error
`net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

```
SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 300,
              child: WebView(
                initialUrl: 'http://dev.xxxxx.com',
                javascriptChannels: Set.from([
                  JavascriptChannel(
                      name: 'Print',
                      onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
                        strr = message.message;
                        print(message.message);
                      }),
                ]),
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController wvCont) {
                  _wvcntr = wvCont;
                },
              ),
            ),
```

How web app hosted on local IIS can we accessed in android(by which URL) ?

Comment: When you receive the "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" error message, it means that no IP address matching the website domain name you entered was found. I suggest you try to access the application using IP address.

Comment: @DingPeng I have hosted this local web app in IIS by creating a new website under IIS and setting it's domain name in `hosts` file.

Comment: I think this should be a DNS resolution problem. Have you tried to use the IP address to access the service?